# Generate a comma delimited string from items in a HTML List Box (multiple select) with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, string, textbox, listbox

So if you have a html List Box, also called a multiple select, and you want to generate a comma delimited string that lists all the values in that List Box you can you can do that with the following example. The list_to_string() js function is the only important thing here.  You can play with this page at http://josh.gourneau.com/sandbox/js/list_to_string.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    function list_to_string()
    {
        var list = document.getElementById('list');
        var chkBox = document.getElementById('chk');
        var str = document.getElementById('str');
        textstring = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < list.options.length; ++i){
            comma = ",";
            if (i == (list.options.length)-1){
                comma = "";
            }
            textstring = textstring + list[i].value + comma;
            str.value = textstring;
        }

    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <select name="list" id="list" size="3" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="India">India</option>
            <option value="US">US</option>
            <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" id="str" name="str" />
        <br /><br />
        <input type="button" id="chk" value="make a string!" name="chk" onclick="list_to_string();"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know what the policy is on posting answers to your own questions.  I just wanted a way to share this little tip.

Comment: and what was the actual question here?

Comment: Last time I checked, answering your own questions is OK, even encouraged. However, it is better to put the question part in the question and the answer part in the answer :)

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks for the idea shared. GBU ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String concatenation is very slow on IE, use an array instead:

```
function listBoxToString(listBox,all) {
    if (typeof listBox === "string") {
        listBox = document.getElementById(listBox);
    }
    if (!(listBox || listBox.options)) {
        throw Error("No options");
    }
    var options=[],opt;
    for (var i=0, l=listBox.options.length; i < l; ++i) {
        opt = listBox.options[i];
        if (all || opt.selected ) {
            options.push(opt.value);
        }
    }
    return options.join(",");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use array.join(','); to create a comma separated list from an array.

Something like this, only better:

```
var list_to_string = function() {
    var opts = document.getElementById('list').options;
    var i = 0, len = opts.length, a = [];
    for (i; i<len; i++) {
        a.push(opts[i].value);
    }
    document.getElementById('str').value = a.join(',');
}
```

Comment: hasOwnProperty is non-portable; use a normal `for (var i= 0; i<opts.length; i++)` loop in preference.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be simply done by using the `Request.Form(control.UniqueID)` to pull the already comma delimited values that are already present for a multiselect listbox.